# How to create an array from txt file with numpy.loadtxt with no delimiter

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a file that it's content is:

```
30373
25512
65332
33549
35390
```

So i want to create a **2D (matrix)** array of the file content

like this

```
[[3. 0. 3. 7. 3.]
 [2. 5. 5. 1. 2.]
 [6. 5. 3. 3. 2.]
 [3. 3. 5. 4. 9.]
 [3. 5. 3. 9. 0.]]
```

So i try this

```py
import numpy as np

print(np.loadtxt('file.txt'))
```

But this gave me the following

```
[30373. 25512. 65332. 33549. 35390.]
```

So it's not the answer that i excepted

And also there is an parameter called `delimiter` in method

```py
import numpy as np

print(np.loadtxt('file.txt', delimiter=''))
```

And this was not the excepted answer too

So can any one help me to figure out this problem.

[EDIT]

It's easy to use the following codes

```
array = [i.split() for i in open('file.txt').read().splitlines()]
```

But i want to know, is it possible to do this by `numpy`?

Comment: You are probably just going to have to "manually" parse your file, it isn't in any standard format, but it should be pretty straightforward

Comment: So just something like `[list(map(float, row.strip())) for row in f]` to create a list of lists then you can create a `numpy` array from that

Comment: Or better yet, make whatever is outputting your file to use a standard format, like csv

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` with `delimiter=[1,1,1,1,1]` might do what you want.  This specifies the column width for each field.

Comment: Just `delimiter=1` works, without having to know the size of the line.

Answer (score 1):

coniferous was not that far, tho, by replacing `loadtxt` with `genfromtxt`, even if that was not just it.

`genfromtxt`'s `delimiter` option can be either a string describing what separates two fields (eg, `','`), or it can also be an integer, which is then the size of the field (for fixed size field format).

So, in your case

```py
np.genfromtxt('file.txt', delimiter=1)
```

does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read ffile using python to list & then typecast to float as follows & then convert to numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
with open(r"text_file.txt") as f:
  data = [x.rstrip('\n').split(" ") for x in f.readlines() ]
new = []
for x in data:
    for y in x:
        s =list(map(float,str(y)))
        new.append(s)
npa = np.asarray(new, dtype=np.float32)
print(npa)
```

Gives #

```
[[3. 0. 3. 7. 3.]
 [2. 5. 5. 1. 2.]
 [6. 5. 3. 3. 2.]
 [3. 3. 5. 4. 9.]
 [3. 5. 3. 9. 0.]]
```

> Note: There could a functional approch. i'm not aware of any
> functional approches to solve this. so I solved step by step